# How to display the paid and unpaid amount of Order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

**CUSTOMER TABLE**

```
+------------+----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------------+
| CustomerID | Fname    | Mname | Lname | Contact_no  | Address                     | Valid_id | Credit_Limit |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------------+
|          7 | John     | Dale  | Doe   | 09123654789 || NULL     |     5000.000 |
|          8 | Jane     | Dale  | Doe   | 09987654123 |  | NULL     |     1500.000 |
|         91 | Kurdapya | Buang | Selos | 09741258963 |  | NULL     |     5000.000 |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------------+
```

**ORDER TABLE**

```
+---------+------------+----------------+----------+------------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | DateOfPurchase | Discount | DueDate    |
+---------+------------+----------------+----------+------------+
|      82 |          7 | 2022-04-17     | 0        | 2022-05-17 |
|      83 |         91 | 2022-04-17     | 0        | 2022-05-17 |
|      84 |          8 | 2022-04-17     | 0        | 2022-05-17 |
|      85 |         91 | 2022-04-17     | 0        | 2022-05-17 |
|      86 |          7 | 2022-04-17     | 0        | 2022-05-17 |
|      87 |         91 | 2022-04-18     | 0        | 2022-05-18 |
|     109 |          7 | 2022-04-25     | 0        | 2022-05-25 |
+---------+------------+----------------+----------+------------+
```

**PAYMENT TABLE**

```
+-----------+------------+---------+------------+----------+
| PaymentID | CustomerID | OrderID | PayDate    | Amount   |
+-----------+------------+---------+------------+----------+
|        20 |          7 |      82 | 2022-04-25 |  800.000 |
|        21 |         91 |      83 | 2022-04-17 | 2500.000 |
|        22 |         91 |      85 | 2022-04-17 |  200.000 |
|        23 |         95 |      88 | 2022-04-18 | 2122.000 |
|        24 |         96 |      90 | 2022-04-25 |  577.000 |
|        25 |         97 |     111 | 2022-04-25 |    0.000 |
|        26 |         98 |     114 | 2022-04-25 |  166.000 |
|        27 |         99 |     115 | 2022-04-25 | 1740.000 |
+-----------+------------+---------+------------+----------+
```

**ORDER DETAILS TABLE**

```
+-------+---------+-----------+------+
| OR_ID | OrderID | ProductID | QTY  |
+-------+---------+-----------+------+
|   173 |      82 |         5 |    1 |
|   174 |      82 |         9 |    1 |
|   184 |      86 |         5 |    1 |
|   185 |      86 |         9 |    1 |
|   186 |      86 |        13 |    1 |
|   187 |      86 |        17 |    1 |
|   224 |     109 |         3 |    3 |
|   225 |     109 |         6 |    3 |
|   292 |     145 |        20 |    2 |
|   293 |     145 |        12 |    1 |
|   294 |     145 |         8 |    2 |
|   295 |     146 |        14 |    1 |
|   296 |     146 |        11 |    1 |
|   297 |     146 |        12 |    1 |
|   298 |     146 |         3 |    1 |
|   299 |     146 |         6 |    1 |
|   300 |     146 |         7 |    1 |
|   301 |     146 |        16 |    1 |
+-------+---------+-----------+------+
```

I don't know if this is needed but this is my **PRODUCT TABLE**:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+------+
| ProductID | Pname         | Pdesc                 | PUnitPrice | weight    | Unit |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+------+
|         2 | Pepsi         | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    313.000 | 1 Litre   |   12 |
|         3 | Mountain Dew  | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    231.000 | 750 ML    |   12 |
|         4 | Pepsi         | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    620.000 | 1.5 Litre |   12 |
|         5 | Mirinda       | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    620.000 | 1.5 Litre |   12 |
|         6 | Mountain Dew  | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    620.000 | 1.5 Litre |   12 |
|         7 | Mountain Dew  | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    145.000 | 8 oz      |   24 |
|         8 | Pepsi         | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    145.000 | 8 oz      |   24 |
|         9 | Mirinda       | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    145.000 | 8 oz      |   24 |
|        10 | 7up           | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    145.000 | 8 oz      |   24 |
|        11 | Sting         | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    266.000 | 240 ml    |   24 |
|        12 | Tropicana     | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    266.000 | 240 ml    |   24 |
|        13 | Cobra         | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    266.000 | 240 ml    |   24 |
|        14 | Sting         | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    166.000 | 300 ml    |   12 |
|        15 | Cobra         | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    166.000 | 300 ml    |   12 |
|        16 | Mountain Dew  | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    135.000 | 295 ml    |   12 |
|        17 | Mirinda       | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    135.000 | 295 ml    |   12 |
|        18 | Pepsi         | 1 Case Plastic Bottle |    135.000 | 295 ml    |   12 |
|        19 | Ginebra       | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    129.000 | 350 ml    |   24 |
|        20 | San Mig Light | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |   1070.000 | 330 ml    |   24 |
|        21 | Red Horse     | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    535.000 | 500 ml    |   12 |
|        22 | Red Horse     | 1 Case Glass Bottle   |    545.000 | 1 Litre   |    6 |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+------+
```

**WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEND**

I want show all the paid order of customerID 7 and his unpaid orders in one row only. I don't know how to start it with a query. Should I use an If() condition? How to properly query it to achieve my desire output?

My Desired **OUTPUT**:

```
+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| unpaid | paid | Fname | Mname | Lname | Contact_no  | Address                     | Credit_Limit | total    |
+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 2995   | 6014 | John  | Dale  | Doe   | 09123654789 |.                   |     5000.000 | 9009.000 |
+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+----------+
```

**EDIT**

**THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**

**1st attempt:**
I am trying to calculate the unpaid order and this is the **output**:

```
select 
    if(py.Amount IS NULL, sum(od.QTY * p.PUnitPrice), CONCAT(py.Amount - sum(od.QTY * p.PUnitPrice))) as remarks, 
    c.Fname, c.Mname, c.Lname, c.Contact_no, c.Address, c.Credit_Limit, 
    sum(od.QTY * p.PUnitPrice) as total 
from customer c INNER JOIN orders r on r.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
INNER join order_details od on r.OrderID=od.OrderID 
INNER JOIN product p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID 
join payment py 
where c.CustomerID=7
```

**RESULT OF ATTEMPT 1:**

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------+
| remarks     | Fname | Mname | Lname | Contact_no  | Address                     | Credit_Limit | total      |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------+
| -134335.000 | John  | Dale  | Doe   | 09123654789 |                       |     5000.000 | 135135.000 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
SELECT IF(py.OrderID IS NULL, sum(od.QTY * p.PUnitPrice), 0) AS unpaid,
if(py.OrderID IS NOT NULL, sum(od.QTY * p.PUnitPrice), 0) as paid,
sum(od.QTY * p.PUnitPrice) as total,
O.OrderID, O.CustomerID, date_format(O.DateOfPurchase, '%M %d, %Y') AS DateOfPurchase, date_format(O.DueDate, '%M %d, %Y') AS DueDate
from Orders O INNER JOIN order_details od on od.OrderID=O.OrderID
INNER JOIN product p ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Payment py ON py.OrderID = O.OrderID
where O.CustomerID = 7
GROUP by O.OrderID
ORDER by O.OrderID desc
```

**RESULT OF ATTEMPT 2:**

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| unpaid   | paid     | total    | OrderID | CustomerID | DateOfPurchase | DueDate      |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| 1829.000 |    0.000 | 1829.000 |     146 |          7 | April 27, 2022 | May 27, 2022 |
|    0.000 | 2696.000 | 2696.000 |     145 |          7 | April 27, 2022 | May 27, 2022 |
|    0.000 | 2553.000 | 2553.000 |     109 |          7 | April 25, 2022 | May 25, 2022 |
| 1166.000 |    0.000 | 1166.000 |      86 |          7 | April 17, 2022 | May 17, 2022 |
|    0.000 |  765.000 |  765.000 |      82 |          7 | April 17, 2022 | May 17, 2022 |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Note: How to sum all the rows in column paid and unpaid?

Comment: So you can build this query bit by bit, what have you got so far?

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1992) Years`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: [construct SQL query from a human-readable description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) PS This seems likely to be a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregate subqueries over appropriate rows and/or aggregate (maybe distinct) case statements picking rows of (possibly join result) tables; then join the subqueries together.

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. PS Still no MRE here. "cut & paste & runnable". "minimal" data & code. PS But don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are approaching the solution is obviously not working, hence you are asking for help.  Your first query, you are joining to the payment table but no condition limiting to only payments for customer 7.  This might coincidentally work out because there is only one payment record.  But for customers with MORE than one,
your totals will get skewed via Cartesian product result.

What you should do is pre-aggregate purchased completely separate from payments so you will have AT MOST, a single record for the one customer you are looking for.  Now, if you want to apply the results for ALL customers, that just gets a little extra and will cover later.

With each individually, prevents confusion of multiple clutterings going on.

In its SHORTEST, since you only care about the TOTALS Purchased vs Paid, I would NOT care about the totals per EACH order, just the totals per customer.

```
select
        c.Fname, 
        c.Mname, 
        c.Lname, 
        c.Contact_no, 
        c.Address, 
        c.Credit_Limit, 
        coalesce( PQ_Orders.TotalOrders, 0 ) TotalOrders,
        coalesce( PQ_Payments.TotalPaid, 0 ) TotalPayments,
        coalesce( PQ_Orders.TotalOrders, 0 )
            - coalesce( PQ_Payments.TotalPaid, 0 ) BalanceDue
    from 
        customer c 
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select
                    o.customerID,
                    sum( od.qty * p.pUnitPrice ) TotalOrders
                from
                    orders o
                        join order_details od
                            on o.orderID = od.orderID
                            join product p
                                on od.productid = p.productid
                where
                    o.customerid = 7
                group by
                    o.customerID ) PQ_Orders
                on c.customerID = PQ_Orders.customerID
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select
                    py.customerid,
                    sum( py.Amount ) TotalPaid
                from
                    payments py
                where
                    py.customerid = 7
                group by
                    py.customerid ) PQ_Payments
                on c.customerID = PQ_Payments.CustomerID
    where 
        c.CustomerID = 7
```

Now, if you want for ALL customers, just remove all the WHERE clauses so it gets ALL customers.  Each respective inner query gets the customer ID as the data grouping, so if one person has 10 orders and 3 payments, you still have at the per PRE-QUERY (PQ) aggregations, only 1 entry per customer on orders and 1 entry per customer on payments.  Joined back to the main customer table and its applied across-the-board to all.

CLARIFICATIONS to O/P

To help clarify, lets look at what you are asking for.  For a single customer, how much stuff was purchased.  Think of that as one query.  Get all order for that one customer, per the order details and the respective product price and sum it up grouped by the customer.  Now the WHERE clause = 7 for the customer is just because you are about the ONE customer.  But doing without the where would show ALL customers what all their respective purchases were.  You would have AT MOST (because group by customerid) 1 record per customer regardless of them having 1 order, or 274 orders.  Its the total for that customer.

Now, the same exact context for payments.  I dont care what or when they purchased something.  All I care about is payments made by a given customer.  Similarly with or without the WHERE of customer ID = 7 as in purchases explanation.  Again, resulting in a record of only 1 per customer regardless of 1 or 75 payments, 1 record per customer.

So now, you have a 1:1:1 possible ratio of 1 customer to 1 purchase to POSSIBLY 1 payment total.

The LEFT JOIN means, I want the thing to the left (customer), but OPTIONALLY may find something on the right (purchases AND/OR payments).

So the COALESCE() prevents nulls from tripping things up in the calculations.  If there IS a value from the given pre-query of purchases or payments, get it, otherwise, assume zero.  So you could get just the one customer in question, or by removing the WHERE clauses, you could get ALL customers with ALL their total purchases AND ALL their total payments for a full outstanding balance of ALL customers.

Comment: I haven't tried to run this query but I have a question regarding the coalesce? I don't quite understand how it is used in your query? Thank you

Comment: I have an error about the coalsce

Comment: @kaponox, COALESCE() says, grab the value from the first column.  If it has one, great, if not, use the value after the comma.  So, since the subqueries are LEFT-JOIN, you are not GUARANTEED to have a record, such as you have an order, but no payments have been made by that customer.  you would want the ZERO value.  As for the error, I updated.  It should have been PQ_Payments.TotalPaid (both instances) and you should be good.

Comment: This one works but I need to understand this query really. But thank you so much and the query that you gave is exactly what I need so a big thanks

Comment: Can you give a proper documentation about the Pre-Query because this is new to me I don't quite understand how it works?

Comment: @kaponox, see revised answer the Pre-Query is just a query on its own merits but is used in-line directly instead of a normal fixed/known table.  The ALIAS after the parenthesis just gives the query a name to associate the results of that query.  I just call pre-query as I want the results of "whatever this query is" to be known as this alias.  You can also see this done with context of WITH CTE (common table expressions).  But that pulls the entire query in front of the actual query and uses the alias in the query.  Same result if you research it.

Comment: so the PQ is not a reserved word or something?

Comment: @kaponox, correct, I just use "PQ" to indicate... hey, this is MY Pre-Query alias and has no context of an actual table in my database.  So don't look for it :)  Just something I sometimes do, especially when trying to explain WHY something works for someone, not just "here, do it because" mentality.  If you dont understand WHY something works, did the answer help you in the future?

Comment: Yeah it did, but there are some miscalculation about the total order of the customer and to his balance due but im on it. Thank you so much

Comment: @kaponox, only thought is that I saw something about a discount column in some table.  Might that be?  Or, rounding on Qty * price, or rounding at the per Order total vs all products purchased.  Dont know what totals you are getting that indicate wrong, but you can always create a NEW post on helping whatever rounding issues and reference this question as background to.. if it comes to that.

Comment: I've solve it already thanks to your query it gives me so many ideas.